# Why didn't Daredevil do this sooner?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil, daredevil-2015

This will contain some spoilers for early season 2 episodes.

In episode 3 (*New York's Finest*), in this

> [awesome fight sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0CvkiPS5Ks), we see Daredevil place an unconscious Frank Castle in a freight elevator heading for the first floor as he disembarks to take care of the Dogs of Hell in the building.  Daredevil manages to make it to the first floor before the elevator does, and at one point we can clearly see that Castle is still unconscious when the elevator doors open.  After defeating the last of the Dogs of Hell, we can hear police sirens in the distance.  But, in the beginning of the next episode, Frank Castle is still walking free.  There's no indication that he's been in jail or police custody, and given his crimes, I doubt that he'd be free to make bail.  So why didn't Daredevil turn him over to the police after defeating the Dogs of Hell?  I don't recall any indication during this or the next episode that Castle regained consciousness and ran off, and Daredevil certainly wasn't happy with him considering what happened with Grotto.

Comment: I just thought that Daredevil had to make a quick getaway and Frank managed to wake up and escape the police?

Comment: My same thought

Comment: @KevinWorkman  I did consider that, but from what I remember, Daredevil wasn't afraid of the police at this point (now that Fisk and his loyalists were incarcerated) and Daredevil was perfectly capable of escaping them if he had to (such as when Fisk's men attempted to kill him and Vladimir in Season 1).

Comment: @Spar10Leonidas Not being afraid of the police is a bit different than being fine with handing yourself over to a whole crowd of them, especially if you're exhausted and on the verge of passing out yourself.

Comment: Even if the police isn't corrupted and working for a gang, Daredevil may prefer to leave the scene quickly. Some policeman may have some questions for a guy who wears a mask, had just been into a fight and carry a gun.

Comment: I acknowledge that that's a possibility, but the ending to _New York's Finest_ strongly gave me the impression that Castle was going to jail.  I was expecting the next episode to begin with his arrest being front page news.  So, the main point of my question is if there is any official in-universe explanation for it, whether they explain it on the show (and I somehow missed it) or some other media.

Comment: Isn't there a shot of the freight elevator being completely empty after Daredevil finishes fighting? I assumed that Castle woke up during the fight and just left specifically so Daredevil couldn't hand him over.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  I just re-watched it, and it looks like you are correct.  I hadn't realized that when he was looking out towards the street (with the flaming motorcycles and hearing the approaching sirens) that he was actually looking through the elevator doors.  I thought that he was looking through the front door of the building and that the shot was meant to indicate that he had neutralized all of the Dogs of Hell.  So, it seems like it may have been a little bit of a poor editing decision.  It happened so quickly that I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the answer had the same spoilers as the question:

> The freight elevator has 2 doors. One opens into the building, the other into the alley. If you watch when Daredevil leaves he exits through the freight elevator's rear door, which is now open. The implication being that his prisoner opened the rear door and snuck out that way while Daredevil was fighting.

Comment: I just re-watched it, and it looks like you are correct.  I hadn't realized that when he was looking out towards the street (with the flaming motorcycles and hearing the approaching sirens) that he was actually looking through the elevator doors.  I thought that he was looking through the front door of the building and that the shot was meant to indicate that he had neutralized all of the Dogs of Hell.  So, it seems like it may have been a little bit of a poor editing decision.  It happened so quickly that I didn't catch it.